# Linux terminal: nicely formatted -h output

Tags: python, linux, command-line, terminal

So I wrote my first python program with command line argument support. Problem is I want my -h help message to display on the (Linux) terminal in a table like format:

```
-i    Description for input
-o    Description for output
-x    Longer description that needs
      more lines than one
```

But with my basic string and print knowledge I cant seem to get the format right. How can I achieve that the multi-line description is flush and does not reach into the arguments section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest skipping doing the parsing yourself and [use the argparse Python module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Perfect, I was using the `getopt` module, but argparse does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I suggest skipping argparse and going straight ahead to [docopt](http://docopt.org/).

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that the "[batteries are included](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included)." Specifically, I recommend that you use the provided [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module.

Second, the answer to your particular question is to use the [width specifier of the format spec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), like so:

```
fmt_string = '{:7s}{:s}'
print fmt_string.format('-i', 'Description for input')
print fmt_string.format('-o', 'Description for output')
print fmt_string.format('-x', 'Longer description that needs')
print fmt_string.format('', 'more lines than one')
```